# Issue For Integrating GWT with IntelliJ 12

Tags: java, gwt, intellij-idea, facet

i've just downloaded IntelliJ 12.1.4 and i'm facing an issue for creating frow scratch a GWT project.

In the panel 'Project Structure' , when i click on 'Facets' and then on the '+', it only shows me 'Android Facet will be added to selected module'.

And even on the panel 'Add Frameworks Support' , there's no GWT label with a checkbox.

Does anyone have an answer on how to enabling GWT ?

Thanks a lot for replying.

Comment: Community Edition does have GWT Support. It is not installed or turned on. You need to browse and install the plugin from repository.

Answer (score 3):

Goto Settings -> Plugins -> Check GWT-Support. (Or press CTRL+ALT+S to open the settings dialog).

[image]

That should also give you some additional project wizards and facets.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.   It's a Community Edition.  And when i go to settings there's no label 'GWT Support' and even if i browse the repositories. Obviously CrazyCoder is right (i've followed his link) i need the ultimate Edition in order to develop a GWT project. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that GWT plugin is turned on. Go to File -> Settings -> Plugins and check **GWT Support**. Then try to [enable corresponding facet](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-gwt-support.html) for you project.